# Dashing dashboard. How to change the 'updatedAtMessage' to be in twelve hour time?

Tags: dashing

I am creating a dashboard with Dashing. In the html for the widgets I have: data-bind="updatedAtMessage", which I got from when I downloaded dashing to display when the widget was updated. I have searched everywhere and cannot seem to find where this message is coming from. I am looking to convert this into 12 hour time because right now it is in 24 hour time.

Answer (score 0):

Dashing uses [BatmanJS filters](http://batmanjs.org/docs/api/batman.view_filters.html). Here's a pretty horrible solution changing `widgets/number/number.html`.

```
<p class="updated-at" data-bind="updatedAtMessage | replace '13:','1:' | replace '14:','2:' | replace '15:','3:' | replace '16:','4:' | replace '17:','5:' | replace '18:','6:' | replace '19:','7:' | replace '20:','8:' | replace '21:','9:' | replace '22:','10:' | replace '23:','1:' "></p>
```